# Maximal ideals for the commutative ring formed by all infinite sequences of rational numbers that are constant after a point

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am being asked to find all maximal ideals in a ring $A$, where $A$ is the commutative ring formed by all infinite sequences of rational numbers that are constant after a point, i.e. all $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...)$ such that $a_n=a_{n+1}=\cdots$.

I've seen a questions related to this but A in that case is formed by real numbers, so I think this case may be different.

I don't know how to begin this question...

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: Presumably the ring structure is pointwise. For every $n$ there's the maximal ideal given by the kernel of the projection to the $n^{th}$ coordinate. There is also the maximal ideal given by the kernel of the map sending a sequence to its eventual value. Can you find any others or show that none exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's find some maximal ideals. For each coordinate, $n\in\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}\NN$, we have a homomorphism $\pi_n : A\to \newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}\QQ$ given by projecting onto the $n$th coordinate. This is a surjective homomorphism to a field, so its kernel is a maximal ideal. Call it $\newcommand{\mm}{\mathfrak{m}}\mm_n$. This is the set of sequences with $n$th coordinate 0. There is also the homomorphism $\lim : A\to \QQ$, which takes the limit of the sequence. Again this is a surjective homomorphism to a field, so $\mm_\infty := \ker\lim$, the set of all sequences which are eventually 0, is a maximal ideal as well.

Now we want to show that these are the only possible maximal ideals. Let $e_i$ be the sequence that is 0 at indices other than $i$ and $1$ at $i$. Then $e_ie_j = 0$ when $i\ne j$, so if $\mm$ is maximal, and $e_i\not \in \mm$ for some $i$, $e_j\in \mm$ for all other $j$, and since $(1-e_i)e_i=0$, $(1-e_i)\in\mm$ as well, and you can check that these generate $\mm_i$. Otherwise, $e_i\in \mm$ for all $i$, and you can check that these elements generate $\mm_\infty$. Hence these are all the maximal ideals.

**Edit**

Editing in response to ZFR's comment below to attempt to clarify the second paragraph.

To be precise, either $e_i$ is not in $\mm$ for some $i$, in which case $\mm$ contains the elements $e_j$ for $j\ne i$ and $1-e_i$, and these elements $\{e_1,\ldots,e_{i-1},1-e_i,e_{i+1},\ldots\}$ generate $\mm_i$. Otherwise $e_i$ is in $\mm$ for all $i$, and the set of elements $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n,\ldots\}$ generates $\mm_\infty$.

Comment: Most of your answers make great sense to me. Only one point I don't understand. At the end of your answer, why ei itself generates ker lim?

Comment: Sorry the collection of all $e_i$ generate the kernel of $\lim$, not just a single $e_i$.

Comment: Oh! That makes your answer whole and very understandable!!

Comment: Np, glad it was helpful

Comment: The result and this very clear proof are valid if one replaces $\mathbb Q$ by a completely  arbitrary commutative ring. +1

Comment: Sorry but the second paragraph of your proof is a bit unclear to me. How it follows that any maximal ideal of $A$ is either $\mathfrak{m}_i$ or $\mathfrak{m}_{\infty}$? Would be very grateful for clarification!

Comment: You mean than infinite set of elements, namely $\{e_1,\dots, e_{i-1},1-e_i,e_{i+1},\dots\}$ generates $\mathfrak{m}_i$?

Comment: @ZFR edited to try to clarify. Let me know if it was helpful

Comment: Thanks for edition! But let me ask you the question: You mean that $\mathfrak{m}_i=\langle  e_1, \dots, e_{i-1},1-e_i,e_{i+1},\dots\rangle$, right? But what do you mean by $\langle e_1, \dots, e_{i-1},1-e_i,e_{i+1},\dots\rangle$ the set of inifinite linear combinations? If yes the infinite sum does not make sense.

Comment: @ZFR No, just finite linear combinations.

Comment: You know there are some unclear moments. You say that if some $e_i \notin \mathfrak{m}$ but all others $e_j$ in it. What about the following cases: 1) none of them belongs to $\mathfrak{m}$? 2) What if $e_1, e_3\notin \mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: @ZFR, in the second paragraph I say that the fact that $e_ie_j=0$ when $i\ne j$ implies that if some $e_i$ isn't in $\mm$, then all of the others are. Thus there are only two cases. Some $e_i$ isn't in $\mm$, or all of them are in $\mm$.

Comment: Finally, I've got your solution! Very nice and elegant! +1. BTW, thanks a lot for explanation!

Comment: @ZFR No worries. It's always nice to find out that an answer from a year ago is still helpful.